# How to style with css the <Tooltip> of Recharts lib

Tags: javascript, recharts

I'm trying to customize the Recharts Tooltip, but even reading the documentation, I can't apply css.
Below is the current and how I want to style.

**Now**:
[image: Now]

**Objective**:
[image: Objective]

Comment: Please translate the title too

Comment: There's a couple of problems with your question. 1. Your title appears to be in Portuguese and Stack Overflow is English only (you could ask in your presumably native language on [pt.so]); 2. We'd like to see code as text.